# .htaccess Environments not working

Tags: .htaccess

I've recently started to work with .htaccess and I can't get the environments (I think that's how are they called) to work. I basically have this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} >0600       
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} <1800       
RewriteRule ^page\.html$ default.html [L]      
RewriteRule ^page\.html$ defaultNight.html [L]
```

I'm not sure what's the problem. This is the only code I have in my .htaccess file. Do I have to make a separate directory of default.html and defaultNight.html? I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite conditions don't look right. You can have rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# serve default.html between 8AM to 6PM
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} >07   
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} <19       
RewriteRule ^page\.html$ default.html [L]      

RewriteRule ^page\.html$ defaultNight.html [L]
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Maybe it's because I have the default.html set as default site page?

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? I didn't provide you a solution since you didn't describe your problem. How did you test this rule?